# perl - escape special characters in string without quotemeta

Tags: regex, string, perl, special-characters

I have a Perl string with special characters and newlines which needs to be passed to a command line utility (which does not accept special chars unless escaped).

How do I substitute each special character with preceding `\`?

I could substitute each char separately, but want to know whether there is a better way?

String comes as follows when read from a cell in a spreasheet.

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.example.com/test/testpage.aspx?ID=OO3JUPVSWjs%3d&ContentTypeId=qbeAILfmBIE%3d" />
```

I tried `$str =~ /^\Q$str\E/;`

but that fails when the variable is passed to the command line utility.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you've already pointed out, you can just use [`quotemeta`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html)

```
$str = quotemeta $str;
```

However, if that isn't good for whatever reason, you can just build your own character class of characters that you want to escape

```
$str =~ s/([\\'"])/\\$1/g;
```

Comment: yeah the above regex would help, but failing when I add & , ? , % in the regex , maybe I am adding it wrong. 
$item=~ s/([\\'"#?&;%*])/\\$1/g;

Comment: $item=~ s/([\\'"#?;%*&])/\\$1/g;   ## This appears to be working

Answer (score 0):

You can build the pattern and perform the match separately:

```
my $pattern = "$bar";
my $regex = "\Q$pattern\E";

if ( q(foo $bar baz) =~ /$regex/ ) {
    print "match\n"
}
else {
    print "no match\n"
}
```